# If match found yes/ no, two different tables, two different values

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I did not see something like this in other questions/ forums so hopefully it can be done.

Need to know if values from one table are in another, checking to see if there is a match.

- Table 1 in Sheet 1 is used to record "Incoming" data of Part Number and Lot Number.
- Table 2 in Sheet 2 is used to record when record is "Outgoing".

Column A is Part Number, B is Lot number in both Sheets. Part number can repeat, but Lot # will not. Trying to find a way to return a Yes/ No or 1,0 if part number and lot number in Sheet 1 exists in Sheet 2 in Column C of Sheet1. I have attached a Snippet example what I am trying to do. This will help me generate info on if an Incoming record has been completed and left (Outgoing). I do not believe vlookup will work and have tried some different permutations of match. Open for other options. Thanks!!

Edit: Lot # does have to ablity to repeat (not often) but with a different corresponding Part Number. Need to know if there is a match with both Lot# and Part Number as in the Incoming record.

[image: Example of table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2)>0)
```

If there are matches it will return `1` if not `0`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately, I do not believe that will also match if the Lot # and its corresponding Part number match on Sheet2. I have tried the countifs, but as your example shows it will only look for Lot # matches, not both lot # and its corresponding Part Number.

Comment: Yes it will, it will require that both match before returning `1`

Comment: @captcurt see edit.  as you can see even though the PN and the Lot can be found in the list on Sheet2 because they are not paired correctly it still returns `0`.

Comment: You are correct. I put your formula in incorrectly at first. Tried again and it works. Thank you!